# First steps wiht AJAX - can't find mistakes

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm doing my first steps with AJAX and PHP, following a book ("AJAX & PHP: Building Responsive Web Aplicattions"). I tried to do something similar to one of the first exercises on my own. The first time I runned the code it didn't work. I checked it out and I didn't find any mistakes. Then I compared both codes line by line, and they looked exactly the same to me. I couldn't find any difference. The problem is the first code works; the divMessage changes its content at the same time you're writting in the input, but this doesn't happen with my code, and I really can't figure out why, because both codes are practically the same to me.

Original Code (HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="quickstart.js" language="Javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload='process()'>
        Server wants to know your name:
        <input type="text" id="myName"></input>
        <div id="divMessage"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My code (HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload='process()'>
        Ingress a number:
        <input type="text" id="number"></input>
        <div id="textbox"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

=====================
Original Code(JS):=====================

```
// stores the reference to the XMLHttp object
var xmlHttp = createXMLHttpRequest();

// retrieves the XMLHttpRequest object
function createXMLHttpRequest(){
    // will store the reference to the XMLHttp object
    var xmlHttp;
    // if running IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject){
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch(e) {
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }
    // if running Mozilla or other browsers
    else {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } 
        catch(e) {
            xmlHttp = false;
        }   
    }
    // return the object created or display an error message
    if(!xmlHttp){
        alert("Error creating the XMLHttpRequest object.");
    }
    else{
        return xmlHttp;
    }
}

// make asynchronus HTTP request using XMLHttpRequest object
function process(){
    // proceed only if the XMLHttpRequest object isn't busy
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == 0){
        // retrieves the name typed by the user on the form
        // La función encodeURIComponent() reemplaza todos los caracteres 
        // que no se pueden utilizar de forma directa en las URL por su representación hexadecimal.
        name = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("myName").value);
        // execute the quickstart.php page from the server
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "quickstart.php?name=" + name, true);
        // define the method to handle server responses
        // the function is be called automatically when the state of the request changes
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        // make the server rqeuest
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    else{
        // if the connection is busy, try again after one second
        setTimeout('process()', 1000);
    }
}

// executed automatically when a message is received from the server
function handleServerResponse(){
    // move forward only if the transaction has completed
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
        // status of 200 indicates the transaction has completed successfully
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200){
            // extract the XML retrieved from the server
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            //obtain the document element (the root element) of the XML structure
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            // get the text message, wich is in the first child
            // of the document element
            helloMessage = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
            // update the client display using the data received from the server
            document.getElementById("divMessage").innerHTML = helloMessage;
            // restart sequence
            setTimeout('process()',1000);
        }
        // a HTTP status different than 200 signal error
        else {
            alert ("There was a problem accessing the server: " + xmlHttp.statusText);
        }
    }
}
```

My Code (JS):

```
var xmlHttp = createXMLHttpRequest();

function createXMLHttpRequest(){
    var xmlHttp;
    if (window.ActiveXObject){
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false();  
        }
    }
    else {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        }
        catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;    
        }
    }
    if(!xmlHttp){
        alert ("El objeto XMLHttpRequest no pudo ser creado.");
    }
    else {
        return xmlHttp;
    }   
}

function process(){
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp == 0){
        number = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("number").value);
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "test.php?number=" + number, true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    else {
        setTimeout("process()", 1000);
    }
}

function handleServerResponse(){
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200){
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            helloMessage = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
            document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML = helloMessage;
            setTimeout("process()",1000);
        }
        else {
            alert ("Hubo un problema al acceder al servidor: " + xmlHttp.statusText);
        }

    }   
}
```

=====================
Original Code(PHP):=====================

```
<?php
// generate the XML output
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
// generate the XML header
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>';
// create the <response> element
echo '<response>';
// retrieve the user name
$name = $_GET['name'];
// generate output depending of the user name received from client
$usernames = array('PABLO','JOSE','JUAN','CARLOS','YODA');
if (in_array(strtoupper($name), $usernames))
    echo 'Hello ' . htmlentities($name);
else if (trim($name) == '')
    echo 'Stranger, please tell me your name.';
else
    echo htmlentities($name) . ', I don\'t know you.';
// close the <response> element
echo '</response>';
?>
```

My Code (PHP):

```
<?php
    header ('Content-type: text/xml');
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>';
    echo '<response>';
        $number = $_GET['number']
        echo 'El número ingresado es:  ' . htmlentities($number);
    echo '</response>';
?>
```

Comment: Are you aware of the awesome developer tools available in the Chrome browser?  You can look at the raw html (which is generated by your php file at the server) and you can look at the javascript code live.  The dev tools will also show you any javascript errors.  See `https://developer.chrome.com/devtools`  Also, what are you using for your php server?  Online or local host?

Comment: `setTimeout("process()", 1000);` might be causing issues, that you are facing. AJAX calls arent supposed to be called that way. You are simply making AJAX call every second and ending up no of ajax call =  no of seconds

Comment: I had to use syntax like that back when early versions of IE didn't handle callback references properly. That should just be `setTimeout(process,1000)`

Comment: `if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp == 0){`   what's `xmlHttp == 0` ?

Comment: I'm using a localhost. It supossed to be xmlHttp.readyState == 0. I fixed that and setTimeout(process,1000), but it's still not working. 

@DavidW, i juts followed the book's intruction, and the original code works fine. Anyway, I delete both sentences and didn't work out.

Comment: I fixed, it was just a semi colon missed in the php file. I want to kill my self now. Absolutely noob mistake. Thanks @zipzit for the advice, it was really helpfull, I finded the error with that tool, and thanks all for the time.

Comment: Ha, we ALL have been there.  Good luck.